# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error using Selenium ChromeDriver Chrome with Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating a google form spam bot so that I can get random submission for my homework assignement;however I hav the eror: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
note I am on Pycharm
and I am using the code in this link:(https://github.com/endeneer1/google-form-autofilling-spam-bot-using-Python-multiple-choice-questions/blob/master/google-form-spambot.py)`

I have looked on different threads but I can't find the answer.

```
import time
import random
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = r"C:\\Users\\LORD\\Desktop\\max spam shit\\chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.chrome(chromedriver)

link = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1mUG- 
vnGYMCyVP17chfx2bzszKkb4NHDLajrOMFbgi1I/viewform? 
edit_requested=true&fbzx=1367418473376240610'
driver.get(link)
```

normally the bot opens a google page brings up the submission,fills it in then ,submits it rince and reapeat but It just comes with the error :C:\python\python.exe "C:/mblock python shit/gg.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/mblock python shit/gg.py", line 6, in 
    driver = webdriver.chrome(chromedriver)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

In the line `driver = webdriver.chrome(chromedriver)` `chrome` is a module. You should call `webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)` where `Chrome` is a class.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

...implies that the call to **ChromeDriver** to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session was not valid.

---

### Solution

You need to replace the lower-case **`c`** as in `chrome` with upper-case **`C`** i.e. replace:

```
driver = webdriver.chrome(chromedriver)
```

With:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
```